# How to access Reddit login API using JS/jQuery and not node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reddit

According to http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_login, its a POST request, but JSONP does not allow POST.

So doing this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.reddit.com/api/login/",
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
     user:"xxxxx",
    passwd:"xxxxx",
    //url:"http://krugman.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/12/28/bitcoin-is-evil/?smid=tw-NytimesKrugman&seid=auto&_r=0",
    api_type:"json"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(result){
        alert('success');
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error:function(xhr,status,error){
        alert(status);
    }
});
```

still sends a GET request and I get a 404.. Without JSONP, I obviously get a cross domain error. Any hint what I am doing wrong?

Also, aren't there any pure JS wrappers for Reddit? There are a few in node.js but none in JS/jQuery. I am looking to write a Chrome Extension.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Were you able to find a solution?